# Custom page shows "The page u requested canot be found " in opencart

Tags: opencart, file-not-found

I've create a custom page in opencart. but it shows not found... Below showing code am using for creating the page...Am new to opencart.so i didn't find the mistake.anybody please help...Thanks

My files are

in    `catalog/controller/category/category.php`
Code is

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php //echo $column_left; ?><?php echo $column_right; ?>
<div id="rightside" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php echo $content_top; ?>  
 <div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div class="box-category">
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <li>
          <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
          <ul>
            <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
            <li>
              <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
              <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

In    `catalog/view/theme/new/template/category/category.tpl`
code is

```
<?php

class ControllerCategoryCategory extends Controller {

    protected function index($setting) {
        $this->language->load('category/category');

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $parts = explode('_', (string) $this->request->get['path']);
        } else {
            $parts = array();
        }

        if (isset($parts[0])) {
            $this->data['category_id'] = $parts[0];
        } else {
            $this->data['category_id'] = 0;
        }

        if (isset($parts[1])) {
            $this->data['child_id'] = $parts[1];
        } else {
            $this->data['child_id'] = 0;
        }

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');

        $this->data['categories'] = array();

        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $data = array(
                    'filter_category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                if ($setting['count']) {
                    $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                        'name' => $child['name'] . ' (' . $product_total . ')',
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                    );
                } else {
                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'category_id' => $child['category_id'],
                        'name' => $child['name'],
                        'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                    );
                }
            }

            $data = array(
                'filter_category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                'filter_sub_category' => true
            );

            if ($setting['count']) {
                $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data);

                $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                    'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                    'name' => $category['name'] . ' (' . $product_total . ')',
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
                );
            } else {
                $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                    'category_id' => $category['category_id'],
                    'name' => $category['name'],
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
                );
            }
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/category/category.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/category/category.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/category/category.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
    }

}

?>
```

In    `catalog/language/english/category/category.php`

Code is

```
<?php
$_['heading_title'] = 'Categories';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index function in your controller class must be public, not protected. Try to change that to public see if that solves the problem.

By the way I don't know how you want to pass $settings to index(). To my knowledge, you shouldn't be able to do that :)